# How can I read the contents of Windows's certlm.msc to a Keystore in java?

Tags: java, windows, ssl-certificate, keystore

On Windows 10/11, I can either import a certificate to certmgr.msc and certlm.msc. If I understand this right, **certmgr.msc** stores the certificates and keys of the **local user**, while **certlm.msc** stores the certificates and keys of the **local machine**.

I can read certificates which were imported to certmgr.msc with a java application like this:

```
KeyStore keyStore;
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
keyStore.load(null, null);

KeyStore trustStore;
trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT");
trustStore.load(null, null);
```

However this code snippet does not read the certificates and keys which I imported to certlm.msc. How can I do that?

Comment: .msc files are console manager plugins, not certificates.

Comment: I did not say, they are certificates. They are certificate manager tools.